# A square matrix (XX^T) made from column vector X always has an eigen vector as X

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank, transpose

I was asked in an interview that

> Given a column vector $X$ of order $n\times1$, when we obtain the matrix $XX^T$ (order $n\times n$), give at least one of the eigenvectors of the matrix $XX^T$ without any calculation, just by looking

Observing that all the columns of the matrix $XX^T$ are dependent on the column vector $X$, thus there is only one independent vector basis in the column space of $XX^T$, thus rank of $XX^T$ is $1$. Hence in row echelon form of $XX^T$, there is only one row and thus, $XX^T$ has $n-1$ eigenvalues as $0$ and one eigenvalue is non-zero.

With their help I was able to conclude from trace property of a matrix that the non-zero eigenvalue was **(sum of square of each element in column vector $X$)**.

But eigenvector I could not found during interview but by their surprised look, it was evident that The eigenvector was hiding in plain sight and I could not see!

Later taking examples, I found $X$ to be an eigenvector.

I could prove it by brute force taking general $(n\times1)$ column vector and then constructing $XX^T$ with all columns dependent

> then the product $XX^T\times X$, will have in first row of product a multiple of first row of any of the column and similarly in all rows, and I could show that the **eigenvector $X$ is corresponding to non-zero eigenvalue**

But, is there a CLEAN method, like from vector spaces geometric interpretation or property of $XX^T$ or anything much more conceptual than brute force general example taking?

Comment: $(XX^T)X=X(X^TX)=\|X\|^2X$ so for $X\ne0,X$ is an eigenvector of $XX^T$ with eigenvalue $\|X\|^2$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri How did you do  $ (XX^T)X=X(X^TX)=\|X\|^2X  $ ? Exactly this thing I felt to be happening, but Why? Like I am not able to visualize or logically deduce. Could you explain a bit please or any links?

Comment: The reason for the first equality is that matrix multiplication is associative. The reason for the second inequality is that $X^TX$ is the square of the norm of $X$ which is a scalar.

Comment: WoW! Now I can see it clearly. thank you. And also now its evident that why the panel was so surprised that "$X$ was not obvious to me! Just post-multiplying $X$ reduces it in span of X again! Appreciate your efforts!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @ShubhamJohri On a side-note. The other eigen values as known to be all "0", and X is symmetric, thus all Eigen vectors orthogonal. But what other deductions I can use to FIND out eigen vectors without brute-force?

Comment: Note that if $v\ne0$ is orthogonal to $X$, then $v$ is an eigenvector of $X^TX$ with the eigenvalue $0$ since $(XX^T)v=X(X^Tv)=0=0v$. So if $X\ne0$, the eigenspace of eigenvalue $0$ is the orthogonal complement of $\text{span} \{X\}$ and to obtain an orthogonal set of eigenvectors one can just orthogonalize its basis.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri The orthogonal sense was amazing for the eigenvalue 0, but wont be the eigenspace of eigen value 0, be orthogonal complement of span of ${X^T}$ ? As $X^T.v$ is giving us 0 on orthogonality. So, v be orthogonal to $X^T$ ? And As we know that all the eigen vectors would be orthogonal, where X is one eigen vecor, this also saying v is in orthogonal complement of X, like you said! So can you clarify between why span of ${X}$ and not span of ${X^T}$ please?

Comment: The condition for orthogonality of $X,v$ is $X\cdot v=X^Tv=0$ as the dot product of $X,v$ is defined as $X^Tv$ or $v^TX$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that for any vector $v$, $(XX^T)v=X(X^Tv)$, and $X^Tv$ is just the inner product of $X$ with $v$.  So $XX^T$ represents the following linear transformation: given a vector $v$, take its inner product with $X$ to get a scalar, and then multiply that scalar by $X$.  This makes it immediately clear that $XX^T$ has rank $1$ and that its image is the subspace spanned by $X$, and so $X$ is (up to scalar multiples) the only eigenvector with a nonzero eigenvalue.

Geometrically, if $X$ is a unit vector, then this is just the orthogonal projection onto the span of $X$: if you pick an orthonormal basis with $X$ as one of the basis vectors, then the inner product $X^Tv$ represents the coefficient of $X$ when you write $v$ in terms of this basis, and then multiplying that by $X$ gives just the $X$ term of $v$.  In general, you can think of $X$ as a unit vector scaled by some scalar $c$, and then $XX^T$ will just be the orthogonal projection onto the span of $X$ scaled by $c^2$ (since you scaled both $X$ and $X^T$ by $c$ from a unit vector).

Comment: I understand that $X(X^T V)$ is taking the component of v in direction of X vector and this value being scalar, we again use X vector and this scalar to get a vector in span of X. But why this would make  $XX^T$ a matrix with rank 1? not getting that rank deduction from geometry

Comment: @BhartenduKumar The rank of a linear transformation is the dimension of its range-space, which is in this case the linear span of $X$.

Comment: WoW! This clear and deep meaning of $XX^T$ was there. LA is indeed beautiful. Thank you Eric @shubham

Answer (score 1):

By matrix associativity, $(\color{red}{X}\color{blue}{X^T})\color{limegreen}{X}=\color{red}{X}(\color{blue}{X^T}\color{limegreen}{X})=(\color{blue}{X}\cdot\color{limegreen}{X})\color{red}{X}$. Or in [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation), $\color{red}{X_i}\color{blue}{X_j}\color{limegreen}{X_j}=(\color{blue}{X_j}\color{limegreen}{X_j})\color{red}{X_i}$.

Comment: Thank you, actually $|| X ||$ notation was new to me and this (X.X) dot notation, made me familiarize it.